# Which Clojure libraries can I use if I plan to use the clojurescript compiler?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm new to Clojure but my end goal in learning the language is to use the Clojurescript compiler, since I plan on using the generated code on the browser VM.

Since there tutorials are abundant for Clojure and Clojurescript is just another compiler I'm doing the Clojure tutorials, but now I got to a point where I want to know where is the line between the libraries that are core clojure that will compile to javascript fine and the ones that won't.

For example, in the tutorial I'm following for Clojure I was reading this but it seems this is already using deep Java objects, and not core Clojure commons:

```
user=> (.length a-string)
7
user=> (.substring a-string 3)
"name"
user=> (.substring a-string 3 5)
"na"

// And for static methods

user=> (def rt (.getRuntime Runtime))
#'user/rt
user=> (.freeMemory rt)
30462304
```

The beginning of the chapter said *In Clojure, strings are the same as Java strings*, but not that Clojure uses `String` from Java, which is a different thing.

So, if my goal is to develop Clojure targeting the browser, what APIs and types can I use? Is there a simple distinction for this? I imagined that anything that doesn't need to be explicitly required (core libs) would be core Clojure and I wouldn't be tying myself the Java libs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's normal, expected, and idiomatic for Clojure to be written to leverage the underlying platform's library -- whichever target you happen to be using. As such, almost universally, libraries which support both Clojure and ClojureScript explicitly use a tool such as cljx to allow code to be provided for both implementations separately.

Comment: ...which is to say that "core Clojure" doesn't attempt to be complete enough to be used exclusively for large / substantial programs.

Comment: Clojure *does* in fact use `java.lang.String` (in the JVM backend), just as ClojureScript uses native JavaScript strings. I'm not completely clear about the distinction you're drawing -- perhaps there was an implication there that they could be a subclass? -- but nope, no subclasses, nothing special, plain old platform-native objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write code to target both Clojure on the JVM and ClojureScript, see [cljx](https://github.com/lynaghk/cljx).

Without using such tools (to embed code snippets explicitly written for either backend), it is not generally expected that substantial programs will work against both independently.

Comment: if you allow me to use your brain for two more seconds. given that clojure is THE language, and Clojurescript is just a compiler, if I don't really care about targeting the JVM (which I don't), what do you recommend for me to know exactly what parts of clojure I can use or not so I don't get blocked when I compile the code.

Comment: ClojureScript doesn't actually implement 100% of Clojure-the-language; in particular, concurrency constructs such as refs that don't make sense in a single-threaded runtime such as JavaScript simply aren't there at all. This is covered in the ClojureScript documentation.

Comment: Yes, I can guess that threading would not fit for sure, I'm much more concerned with basic things like (.length) and how would I know if this is going to compile to JS or not.

Comment: `(.length "foo")` is, as you say, an interop call, not a Clojure builtin, so it's not to be expected that it'll work unless each runtime's String class independently has such a method.